# renderization of jsp/jstl code fail

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

In my current spring project, my views for insert/update a new record in the database pass to the jsp code two attributes:

- map: List with the fields of the entity class being inserted
- value: Map> where the key is the fields of the class and the value is the list of the fields from the class which the field is declared.

in the jsp code, I iterate over the list for add the form input fields, like this:

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${value[entry]}">
    <c:when test="${entry == '...'}">
    ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    ...
    </c:otherwise>
</c:forEach>
```

I have one block `<c:when>` for each entity from my project and the block `<c:otherwise>` is separated to the primitive values. The full code for this page can be seen here: https://github.com/klebermo/loja.cms/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/common/fields.jsp

My problem is when I try open the view for insert a record for this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="usuario")
    @Order(value=1)
    private Usuario usuario;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="pessoa_fisica")
    @Order(value=2)
    private PessoaFisica pessoaFisica;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="pessoa_juridica")
    @Order(value=3)
    private PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="endereco_entrega")
    @Order(value=4)
    private Endereco endereco_entrega;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="endereco_cobranca")
    @Order(value=5)
    private Endereco endereco_cobranca;
}
```

the two last fields are not renderized on the page. In my tests, when I remove the block `<c:if>` for `contato` from the block `<c:when>` for the field `pessoaJuridica`, the both fields are renderized correctly. Anyone can tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problems seems to be that you added `style="display: none;"` to the wrapping div, hence they are not displayed in the browser.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="pj" style="display: none;">
```

If you remove the style the fields should just show up.

Comment: No, that's not the problem, because none of the two `<div>` are even renderized (I looked at source code of the page, and this two blocks aren't displayed there either). I fit was a problem with the style, at least one block should be displayed (only one is hidden). BTW, the problem is with the block `<div class="panel panel-default" id="entrega">` and `<div class="panel panel-default" id="cobranca" style="display: none;">`.